SemanticKernel function call with local LLM issue
I am trying to create my first demo AI project, and I would like to use Semantic Kernel to connect with my local hosted LLM and use function calls. I am getting responses from the LLM just fine, but I am unable to invoke any of my plugins. I can see that plugins are inserted into json when sending prompt to the LLM like so:
"tools": [
    {
      "type": "function",
      "function": {
        "description": "Gets a list of lights and their current state",
        "name": "Lights-get_lights",
        "parameters": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [],
          "properties": {}
        }
      }
    },

but sadly I am unable to make LLM call my function via Kernel, to fetch data from my plugin. I have tried few models such as: Llama-3.2-3B-Instruct, Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct, Hermes-2-Pro-Mistral-7B, c4ai-command-r-v01. I am using LM Studio to host local server. I am pretty new to LLMs so perhaps I am missing something obvious?
Here is my Program.cs code:
var messageAPIPlatform = "LocalAI";
var url = "http://localhost:1234/v1";
var modelId = "llama-3.2-3b-instruct";

Console.WriteLine($"Example using local {messageAPIPlatform}");

#pragma warning disable SKEXP0010
var kernel = Kernel.CreateBuilder()
    .AddOpenAIChatCompletion(
        modelId: modelId,
        apiKey: null,
        endpoint: new Uri(url))
    .Build();


var chatCompletionService = kernel.GetRequiredService<IChatCompletionService>();

kernel.Plugins.AddFromType<LightsPlugin>("Lights");

// Enable planning
#pragma warning disable SKEXP0001
OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings settings = new OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings()
{
    ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions,
    Temperature = .1,
    ChatSystemPrompt = """
                       Assistant is a large language model.
                       This assistant uses plugins to interact with the software.
                       """
};

// Create a history store the conversation
var history = new ChatHistory();

// Initiate a back-and-forth chat
string? userInput;
do
{
    // Collect user input
    Console.Write("User > ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    // Add user input
    history.AddUserMessage(userInput);

    // Get the response from the AI
    var result = await chatCompletionService.GetChatMessageContentAsync(
        history,
        executionSettings: settings,
        kernel: kernel);

    // Print the results
    Console.WriteLine("Assistant > " + result);

    // Add the message from the agent to the chat history
    history.AddMessage(result.Role, result.Content ?? string.Empty);
} while (userInput is not null);

and my plugin:
public class LightsPlugin
{
    // Mock data for the lights
    private readonly List<LightModel> lights = new()
    {
        new LightModel { Id = 1, Name = "Table Lamp", IsOn = false },
        new LightModel { Id = 2, Name = "Porch light", IsOn = false },
        new LightModel { Id = 3, Name = "Chandelier", IsOn = true }
    };

    [KernelFunction("get_lights")]
    [Description("Gets a list of lights and their current state")]
    [return: Description("An array of lights")]
    public async Task<List<LightModel>> GetLightsAsync()
    {
        return lights;
    }

    [KernelFunction("change_state")]
    [Description("Changes the state of the light")]
    [return: Description("The updated state of the light; will return null if the light does not exist")]
    public async Task<LightModel?> ChangeStateAsync(int id, bool isOn)
    {
        var light = lights.FirstOrDefault(light => light.Id == id);

        if (light == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Update the light with the new state
        light.IsOn = isOn;

        return light;
    }
}

Even though I can see that this plugin is being send to the LLM as a tool. LLM is unable to call this GetLigthsAsync() method when asked about the current state of lights. I am getting an general answer that LLM is not able to answer this question

Edit:
 OllamaConnector 
I tried using solution from this sample implementation of Ollama with function calling sadly without any success. I am using the latest versions of Semantic Kernel and Ollama.

 ChatComplitionAgent and KernelPLuginFactory
I was finally able to invoke function calling with Ollama. Main changes are:

I am using ChatComplitionAgent to send prompts to the LLM instead of ChatCompletionService.
SemanticKernel object is assigned to the ChatComplitionAgent
I am using KernelPluginFactory to create plugins instead of KelnerBuilder.AddFromType.
I am still using OpenAiChatCompletion even though I believe I should be using OllamaConnector
I had to downgrade SemanticKernel library to 1.18.2 version to be able to use ChatComplitionAgent

This solution is not perfect, since I am using old version of SemanticKernel and it's much different than any official guide. However this in the only way I was able to invoke my methods via LLM until now. A solution below is base on this article. I am still wondering why anything else does not work.
Here is the code:
var modelId = "llama3.2";
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:11434";

var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
};

var builder = Kernel.CreateBuilder().AddOpenAIChatCompletion(modelId: modelId!, apiKey: null, endpoint: new Uri(baseUrl!), httpClient: httpClient);
var kernel = builder.Build();

var hostName = "AI Assistant";
var hostInstructions =
    @"You are a friendly assistant";


var settings = new OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings()
{
    Temperature = 0.1,
    ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions,
};

ChatCompletionAgent agent =
           new()
           {
               Instructions = hostInstructions,
               Name = hostName,
               Kernel = kernel,
               Arguments = new(settings),
           };

KernelPlugin lightsPlugin = KernelPluginFactory.CreateFromType<LightsPlugin>();
agent.Kernel.Plugins.Add(lightsPlugin);

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Assistant: Hello, I am your Assistant. How may i help you?");

AgentGroupChat chat = new();

while (true)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("User: ");
    await InvokeAgentAsync(Console.ReadLine()!);
}

async Task InvokeAgentAsync(string question)
{
    chat.AddChatMessage(new ChatMessageContent(AuthorRole.User, question));

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    await foreach (ChatMessageContent content in chat.InvokeAsync(agent))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(content.Content);
    }
}

#pragma warning restore SKEXP0010
#pragma warning restore SKEXP0110


It seems to me that the docs are out of date. Instead of ToolCallBehavior use FunctionChoiceBehavior = FunctionChoiceBehavior.Auto() in your OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings  https://gist.github.com/rippo/00de775cdc27d1161a0b75337cb5afc5

Function calling for local models isn't officially supported when using the OpenAI connector via AddOpenAIChatCompletion.
For more details, see this github issue.
Instead, use the OllamaConnector with AddOllamaChatCompletion() for local function calling.
Here’s a sample implementation of Ollama with function calling for reference.

Note: This may require an updated version of the Semantic Kernel(As of now dotnet-1.31.0 is the latest version).


I tried this solution without any success sadly.

Could you specify the exact error you were facing?
I tested the implementation with a minimal repository, using plugins from the sample and the provided code, and successfully made function calls.
The minimal repo
Though during testing, I encountered some issues with the 1b and 3b Llama models, primarily related to incorrect function parameter generation, which is somewhat expected given the models' limited capabilities.

There was no explicit error but I could see that my methods were never invoked. Thanks to your solution I found my problem. I was using Connectors.Ollama v1.25.0-alpha which was the issue. Updating this nuget to v1.31.0-alpha solved this problem.
Thank you!

If someone is still looking for the answer, function calling is supported only by a limited number of models. Use llama3.2.

You are right. I was finally able to invoke my methods with LLama3.2 but I had to use outdated solution since any code from official sources did not work for me.

This does not work, I have got examples of Llama3.1 and 3.2.

Please try this using Ollama. It looks like an issue with LmStudio.

I did try it with Ollama as well, with the same result unfortunately
